# Vscode how to add box shadow to scroll bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3UhO.png)

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can add box shadows to the vscode scrollbar?

The main purpose here is i want to make scroll bar look like neon.

i found this code on stackoverflow:

`"workbench.colorCustomizations": { "scrollbar.background": "#ff0000" }`

this changes the color of it but i could not find how can add shadows

Comment: you must inject your Custom CSS